# Tenho conjuntos de variáveis armazenando configurações diferentes. Como usar um conjunto específico dependendo da ocasião?

Tags: php

Tenho este ficheiro config.

```
<?PHP
$s_ipserver1 = "10.0.0.101";
$db_porta1    = "3306";
$db_user1     = "user";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "name";

$s_ipserver2 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta2    = "3306";
$db_user2     = "user";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "name";

$s_ipserver3 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta3    = "3306";
$db_user3     = "user";
$db_password3 = "123456";
$db_name3     = "name";
?>
```

E quero convertê-lo em algo parecido como este.

```
<?PHP

$dbL = "1";// Que servidor é este? 1, 2 ou 3.

$s_ipserver1 = "10.0.0.101";
$db_porta1    = "3306";
$db_user1     = "user";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "name";

$s_ipserver2 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta2    = "3306";
$db_user2     = "user";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "name";

$s_ipserver3 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta3    = "3306";
$db_user3     = "user";
$db_password3 = "123456";
$db_name3     = "name";

$s_ipserver  = "$s_ipserver$dbL";
$db_porta    = "$db_porta$dbL";
$db_user     = "$db_user$dbL";
$db_password = "$db_password$dbL";
$db_name     = "$db_name$dbL";
?>
```

Este é um dos ficheiros de ligação.

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$db_host1     = "$s_ipserver1:$db_porta1";
$db_link1     = mysql_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect1  = mysql_select_db($db_name1, $db_link1);
?>
```

E preciso que fique algo parecido como este.

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$db_host      = "$s_ipserver:$db_porta";
$db_link      = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect   = mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
?>
```

Onde está o meu erro? Todos os ficheiros originais estão a funcionar perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não fica o código mais limpo e bonito mas resolve o meu problema que quando o próprio servidor se quiser ligar a ele mesmo escolhendo de 3 ligações possíveis com a pequena variável `$dbL`

Em /pasta/config.php

```
<?PHP

$dbL = "1";// Que servidor é este? 1, 2 ou 3.

$s_ipserver1 = "10.0.0.101";
$db_porta1    = "3306";
$db_user1     = "user";
$db_password1 = "123456";
$db_name1     = "name";

$s_ipserver2 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta2    = "3306";
$db_user2     = "user";
$db_password2 = "123456";
$db_name2     = "name";

$s_ipserver3 = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$db_porta3    = "3306";
$db_user3     = "user";
$db_password3 = "123456";
$db_name3     = "name";
?>
```

Em /pasta/subconnect.php

```
<?php 
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$ipserver  = '$s_ipserver'. $dbL;
$porta     = '$db_porta'. $dbL;
$user      = '$db_user'. $dbL;
$password  = '$db_password'. $dbL;
$name      = '$db_name'. $dbL;

eval("\$ipserver = \"$ipserver\";");
eval("\$porta = \"$porta\";");
eval("\$user = \"$user\";");
eval("\$password = \"$password\";");
eval("\$name = \"$name\";");
?>
```

Em /pasta/connect.php

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/subconnect.php");
$host      = "$ipserver:$porta";
$link      = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect   = mysql_select_db($name, $link);
?>
```

E obrigado @bfavaretto pela paciência e pelo código que me facultou e aos outros também.

Correcção a pedido do @bfavaretto

Opção para /pasta/subconnect.php

```
<?php 
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
$ipserver  = 's_ipserver'. $dbL;
$porta     = 'db_porta'. $dbL;
$user      = 'db_user'. $dbL;
$password  = 'db_password'. $dbL;
$name      = 'db_name'. $dbL;
// Sem eval()
?>
```

Opção para /pasta/connect.php Para sem eval()

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/subconnect.php");
$host      = $$ipserver . ':'. $$porta;
$link      = mysql_connect($host, $$user, $$password) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect   = mysql_select_db($$name, $link);
?>
```

Comment: Tente adaptar seu código para o uso de arrays, como o @bfavaretto mostrou na resposta dele. Evite o uso de `eval` a todo custo, é uma má pratica e só deve ser usado em último caso (que não é o seu caso).

Comment: "Se o eval() é a resposta, você está com certeza fazendo a pergunta errada." - http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php#44008

Comment: @gmsantos, como é aquilo? *"-Tenho um problema. -Já sei, vou usar Regex. >Agora você tem dois problemas."*

Comment: @brasofilo pois é, faltou um regex ai pra validar o IP da config... vai que ...

Comment: @gmsantos o problema é que já tenho 80 ou 90 ficheiros dependentes do config.php e ao alterar para um array que de certeza que ficaria muito mais bem servido todos deixariam de funcionar e tinha que começar a minha guerra toda desde o principio e já tenho alguns meses de pesquisa e de construção nisto pois eu não sou programador nem nada que se pareça.

Comment: "eu não sou programador nem nada que se pareça", aceite o conselho para adaptar o sistema com a melhor forma. Nem sempre uma solução resolve o problema, apenas acaba postergando. (errei a grafia)

Comment: "já tenho 80 ou 90 ficheiros dependentes do config.php" Sugestão entao, deixe as 2 coisas no config.php, a array e as variáveis (inclusive pode montar a array pegando das variáveis, para não ter que atualizar em dois lugares), assim você vai editando aos poucos pro formato novo, sem que o velho pare de funcionar. Assim, você elimina as variáveis só quando tudo estiver funcionando com array, e não corre riscos.

Comment: Agradeço a vossa força e com este tipo de ligação já comecei a eliminar ficheiros pois existiam muitos que fazem a mesma coisa só que de servidores diferentes quando acabar vou expor ficheiro a ficheiro para converter para array porque o config e os connect não são bem como os estou a mostrar

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar [*variable variables*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), mas acho isso extremamente feio e confuso:

```
$dbL = "1";
$s_ipserver1 = "bla";
$servidor = 's_ipserver'. $dbL;
echo $$servidor; // "bla";
```

Seria mais elegante usar arrays:

```
$servidores = array(
    array(
        's_ipserver' => "10.0.0.101",
        'db_porta'    => "3306",
        'db_user'     => "user",
        'db_password' => "123456",
        'db_name'     => "name",
    ),
    array(
        's_ipserver' => "10.0.0.201",
        'db_porta'    => "3306",
        'db_user'     => "user",
        'db_password' => "98765",
        'db_name'     => "foo"
    )
    // etc
);

$indice = 1;
$servidor = $servidores($indice);
echo $servidor['s_ipserver']; // "10.0.0.201"
```

Comment: Você deve ser um bot, só pode :D

Comment: bots não acham nada extremamente feio e confuso :)

Comment: Como eu não posso só escrever "Boa", então "Boa!" :p

Comment: Experimentei fazer da parte feia e o resultado foi o seguinte erro no ficheiro de ligação PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Unknown MySQL server host '$s_ipserver1' (25) in /pasta/connect.php on line 4

Comment: @RjpServidor Como ficou sua linha `$db_link = mysql_connect...`?

Comment: Igual como estava $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die (mysql_error ());

Comment: Você não adaptou meu código? Assim como mostrei `$servidor = 's_ipserver'. $dbL;`, você precisa fazer do mesmo jeito para porta, usuário, etc. Depois pode fazer `$host = $$servidor . ':' . $$porta;`, e só aí usar `$host` na hora de conectar. @RjpServidor

Comment: Sim adaptei e criei um outro ficheiro para assegurar as suas alterações. Posso responder a esta pergunta com todo o código que eu preciso para podermos fazer as alterações necessárias ou tenho que editar a pergunta ??

Comment: @RjpServidor Responder não, e editar a pergunta alteraria a natureza dela. Me passa um link com seu código no pastebin.com

Comment: Nunca usei pastebin mas está aqui em formato TXT no meu servidor [link](http://www.rjpserver.tk/duvida/config.txt)

Comment: `$host = $$ipserver . ':'. $$porta;` @RjpServidor

Comment: Sim já tinha experimentado e o erro é:  `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: $s_ipserver1 in /pasta/connect.php on line 3` `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: $db_porta1 in /pasta/connect.php on line 3` `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user '$db_user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /pasta/connect.php on line 4` `Access denied for user '$db_user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Já fiz a alteração no link com o que tenho feito

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser, @RjpServidor... :(

Comment: Já consegui agora como faço respondo a minha própria pergunta?

Comment: Sim, pode responder @Rjp

Comment: @RjpServidor Vendo sua resposta me toquei do que estava errado no código que você linkou: no subconnect.php, use `'s_ipserver'. $dbL`, **sem cifrão no começo**, e tire o cifrão dos nomes das outras variáveis também. Na minha opinião ainda é um pouco mais limpo que usar o `eval`...

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar arquivos individuais para cada conexão, u como sugeriu o @bfavaretto, criar um array contendo os índices:

```
#pasta/config/database.php
return array(
    'DB1' => array(
             's_ipserver'  => '10.0.0.101',
             'db_porta'    => '3306',
             'db_user'     => 'user',
             'db_password' => '123456',
             'db_name'     => 'name',
             ),

    'DB2' => array(
             's_ipserver'  => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
             'db_porta'    => '3306',
             'db_user'     => 'user',
             'db_password' => '123456',
             'db_name'     => 'name',
             ),

    'DB3' => array(
             's_ipserver'  => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
             'db_porta'    => '3306',
             'db_user'     => 'user',
             'db_password' => '123456',
             'db_name'     => 'name',
             )
);
```

Exemplificando do array com índice

```
# conn database-1
$conn = include_once('/pasta/config/database.php');
$conn = $conn['DB1'];

// output conexão DB1
Array
(
    [s_ipserver] => 10.0.0.101
    [db_porta] => 3306
    [db_user] => user
    [db_password] => 123456
    [db_name] => name
)
```

Exemplo conexão

```
$host       = $conn['s_ipserver'] . ':' . $conn['db_porta'];
$db_link    = mysql_connect( $host , $conn['db_user'] , $conn['db_password'] ) or die( mysql_error() );
$db_connect = mysql_select_db( $db_name, $db_link );
```