# Qual o motivo de alterarmos dinamicamente o nome de uma variável em PHP?

Tags: php

Em PHP, é possível alterar dinamicamente o nome de uma variável utilizando `$$`. Mas qual o motivo dessa possibilidade? Qual é a sua aplicabilidade?

Comment: As vantagens de usar isso são discutíveis (tende a deixar o código mais difícil de ler), mas eu dei um exemplo [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31982).

Comment: O nome disso ai é [variáveis variáveis](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variável variante ou variável variável, como você preferir chamar, pode ser utilizada em **n** casos, mas o mais comum deles é quando precisa criar uma série de variáveis para aplicar em seu sistema de forma que mantenha uma troca de dados de forma um pouco mais segura do que o uso de variáveis globais, por exemplo. Ela permite minimizar um pouco mais seus códigos, para entender melhor observe o exemplo a seguir:

```
// fazendo um post através de uma requisição, imagine quantas linhas eu economizei tendo que escrever cada uma destas variáveis:
$campos = ['nome','email','senha','cidade','uf'];
foreach ($campos as $campo) {
         ${$campo} = sanitize($_REQUEST[$campo]); //usa os filtros automáticos do PHP
}
```

Imagine que meu formulário tivesse mais de 200 campos, e eu tivesse que escrevê-los manualmente, dessa forma:

```
$nome = sanitize($_REQUEST['nome']);
$email = sanitize($_REQUEST['email']);
$senha = sanitize($_REQUEST['senha']);
$cidade = sanitize($_REQUEST['cidade']);
$uf = sanitize($_REQUEST['uf']);
...
```

Eu já estaria dormindo na meio dessa produção antes de chegar no centésimo. É claro que você também pode fazer isso usando array:

```
 $campos = ['nome','email','senha','cidade','uf'];
  foreach ($campos as $key => $campo) {
            $campos[$key] = sanitize($_REQUEST[$campos[$key]]); //usa os filtros automáticos do PHP
    }
```

Mas existem casos que não é possível usar array, como o exemplo abaixo, mesmo que você use array, ainda estará sendo uma variável variante:

```
class Teste {

public $nome = 'Duds';

}  

$teste = new Teste();

$atributo_chamado = "nome";
echo $teste->{$atributo_chamado};
```