# Variável variável em php

Tags: php, variáveis

Preciso gerar uma variável com nome arbitrário. Tenho o seguinte código, que não funciona:

```
$vv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tabela ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
$i=1;
while($v = mysql_fetch_array($vv)){
  $vertical.$i=$v['arquivo'];
  $i++;
}

echo'
<img src="img/fotos/'.$vertical1.'"> <br>
<img src="img/fotos/'.$vertical2.'"> <br>
<img src="img/fotos/'.$vertical3.'">
';
```

Gostaria que a query me retornasse 3 variáveis: `$vertical1`, `$vertical2` e `$vertical3`

Obs: No banco de dados o campo 'arquivo' tem o 'formato' incluso. Ex.: foto.jpg

Obs.2: Acredito que o problema esteja na concatenação `$vertical.$i`...

Comment: Seria melhor mover o echo para dentro do WHILE e usar a variavel que ja é passada, o que acha?

Comment: O código que postei é uma versão resumida da página. No caso real não seria o ideal devido a posição das <img>, que ficam em locais variados. Daí eu teria que fazer varias "query", além de correr o risco de listar 2 vezes a mesma img.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Com [variáveis variáveis](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) seria assim:

```
$varname = 'vertical' . $i;
$$varname = $v['arquivo'];
```

Eu acho isso meio feio e confuso, prefiro usar uma array:

```
<?php
$vv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tabela ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
$vertical = array();

while($v = mysql_fetch_array($vv)) {
    $vertical[] = $v['arquivo'];
}

echo '
    <img src="img/fotos/'.$vertical[0].'"> <br>
    <img src="img/fotos/'.$vertical[1].'"> <br>
    <img src="img/fotos/'.$vertical[2].'">
';
```

PS: Você precisa atualizar todas as suas chamadas `mysql_*` para [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php), pois seu código é [incompatível com versões mais recentes do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579).

Comment: Descobri que eu acho isso "feio e confuso" já faz [mais de 2 anos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31981/tenho-conjuntos-de-vari%C3%A1veis-armazenando-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-diferentes-como-usar-um/31982#31982) hehe

Comment: Utilizei array da forma apresentada e funcionou perfeitamente pra mim. Muito obrigado. Quanto a sugestão de atualizar para mysqli, estou fazendo isso em todo o sistema gradualmente, ainda não cheguei nessa página.

Answer (score 3):

Eu concordo com o @bfavaretto ... O código com `$variavel$i` ficaria meio confuso. Para incrementar usando a resposta dele, coloquei um loop nas imagens, pois caso você altere o `LIMIT` do SQL, então você não precisa adicionar novamente a tag `<img>`, assim ele já faz sozinho:

```
<?php
$vv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tabela ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3");
$vertical = array();

while($v = mysql_fetch_array($vv)) {
    $vertical[] = $v['arquivo'];
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($vertical); $i++){
   echo '<img src="img/fotos/'.$vertical[$i].'"><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo mais do mesmo, poderia apenas delimitar com chaves.

Exemplo:

```
$str1 = 'a';
$str2 = 'b';
${$str1.$str2} = 'c';

echo $ab;
```

Algo mais específico para o código da pergunta:

```
$i = '1';
${'vertical'.$i} = 'foo';

echo $vertical1;
```

Condordo com os comentários sobre o código pois o que está fazendo dificulta a legibilidade. Existem determinados casos onde pode ser bem aplicado, mas não parece ser o caso que apresentou na pergunta. Todavia, não posso julgar se o que faz é certo ou errado pois sou alheio a sua lógica de negócios.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Já solucionei a questão com array mas vou testar também com as chaves para fins de estudo.