# Que utilidade tem esta forma de acessar valores de variaveis

Tags: php, variáveis

```
<?php      
      $Bar = "a";
      $Foo = "Bar";
      $World = "Foo";
      $Hello = "World";
      $a = "Hello";

      $a; 
      $$a; 
      $$$a; 
      $$$$a; 
      $$$$$a; 

?>
```

Em que sentido posso tomar partido desta forma de acessar valor de variáveis do php desta forma, na pratica em que seria util?

Comment: Me lembra muito os ponteiros da linguagem C, quando queres acessar o endereço do endereço do endereço de uma variável `***v;`

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171153/variav%C3%A9l-vari%C3%A1vel-em-php

Comment: E como disse o Diego lá embaixo: na prática, não use isso.

Comment: @bfavaretto tomei a liberdade de adicionar teu link na resposta, achei interessante ok?

Comment: Ok @Diego, sem problemas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variáveis variáveis, variáveis dinâmicas ou ainda variáveis criadas durante a execução no PHP.

É um recurso que nos permite a criação de uma variável através do conteúdo de outra variável.

Para criar uma variável variável utiliza-se de uma variável para servir de identificador para outra que é criada. Para isso utiliza-se duas vezes o símbolo de `$`, ou seja, devemos utilizar `$$`. Veja no exemplo a seguir.

```
<?php

// Declarando o valor da variável $a

$a = 'nome';

/**

 * Criamos $$a, que como possui dois $

 * também pode ser chamada pelo valor da

 * variável $a ou seja "nome"

 */

$$a = 'Mauro';

// Exibo $a e $nome que foi criada dinâmicamente

echo $a . ' : ' . $nome;

?>
```

Como você pode ver no exemplo podemos criar a variável a partir do valor de outra variável. O contrário também é válido ao invés de criarmos a variável, em nosso caso, `$nome` dinamicamente definimos seu valor normalmente no entanto quando formos exibir seu resultado em tela podemos acessar seu valor através de `$$a`, lembrando que para que isto funcione `$a` deve possuir o mesmo valor da variável que será criada em nosso caso “nome”. Neste outro exemplo, usando a sua pergunta, veja como ficaria as saidas:

```
  $Bar = "a";
  $Foo = "Bar";
  $World = "Foo";
  $Hello = "World";
  $a = "Hello";

  $a; //Retorna Hello
  $$a; //Retorna World
  $$$a; //Retorna Foo
  $$$$a; //Retorna Bar
  $$$$$a; //Retorna a

  $$$$$$a; //Retorna Hello
  $$$$$$$a; //Retorna World
```

Na minha opinião, no dia a dia isso não tem utilidade comercial, mas sim para estudos, para aprender como funcionam variáveis criadas na execução.

[Fonte 1](http://aprenderphp.com.br/artigo/variaveis-variaveis-constantes-magicas-e-sintaxe-heredoc-em-strings-no-php/) - [Fonte 2 e Comentários](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php)

PS: Veja a resposta do @bfavaretto nessa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171153/vari%C3%A1vel-vari%C3%A1vel-em-php), vai ter dar uma idéia de uso real.

Answer (score 0):

### Outra opinião

> As variáveis dinâmicas tem utilidade sim como pode ser constatado nos exemplo a seguir.

No envio de um **extenso** formulário ao invés de digitar **trocentas** vezes no código, como por exemplo, `$nome = $_POT['nome']`

> fazendo uso de variáveis dinâmicas a coisa fica bem simplificada, vejam como

```
foreach ( $_POST as $chave => $valor ) {
  // $$chave cria as variáveis com os names dos elementos do formulário
  $$chave = trim( strip_tags( $valor ) );
 }
```

Vou citar outro exemplo de uso dessas `Variáveis variáveis, variáveis dinâmicas ou ainda variáveis criadas durante a execução no PHP`

Tenho uma centena de options como exemplificado abaixo:

```
echo ("<option value=\"youtube.php?n=s5&-----aaED7ZVkg0\"".$s5.">15/07/2016</option>\n");
echo ("<option value=\"youtube.php?n=s4&-----K_nny4LPEw\"".$s4.">15/07/2016</option>\n");
echo ("<option value=\"youtube.php?n=s3&-----u92sZyvhGw\"".$s3.">08/07/2016</option>\n");
echo ("<option value=\"youtube.php?n=s2&-----4BmVYRHypo\"".$s2.">08/07/2016</option>\n");
echo ("<option value=\"youtube.php?n=s1&-----_pM6kaYjc0\"".$s1.">08/07/2016</option>\n");
```

Nesse caso gostaria que o usuário ao clicar em uma opção e ao ser exibido o video, que a option selecionada ficasse `SELECTED`

Repare que estou passando um parâmetro no URL `n=s1`  `n=s2` etc....

Como se poderia deixar o option selecionado `SELECTED` ao ser direcionado para a pagina do video?

Uma forma exaustiva e imensa seria através de:

`if ($_GET["n"]=="s1"){
     $s1="" selected"";
   }elseif($_GET["n"]=="s2"){
     $s2="" selected"";
   } ................
   ..................`

`elseif`uma centena de vezes

**Ai que entra o uso da variável variável**

```
$n = $_GET["n"];
$$n=" selected";
```

Para `$n=s1;` teremos  `$s1=" selected";`

Se me foi útil? passe o mouse na área amarelada abaixo para saber

> Muitissimo útil, economizei centenas de else ifs

Variáveis variáveis, variáveis dinâmicas ou ainda variáveis criadas durante a execução no PHP  [**Creditos**](http://aprenderphp.com.br/artigo/variaveis-variaveis-constantes-magicas-e-sintaxe-heredoc-em-strings-no-php/)

Independente do nome que encontrar por aí em livros ou mesmo pela internet, é um recurso que nos permite a criação de uma variável através do conteúdo de outra variável.

Para criar uma variável variável utiliza-se de uma variável para servir de identificador para outra que é criada. Para isso utiliza-se duas vezes o símbolo de $, ou seja, devemos utilizar $$.

Comment: Nunca tinha pensado sobre isso xD, utilizaria um array

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes o array tb seria enorme não? eu precisei de somente duas linhas

Comment: verdade, agora me colocou a pensar como resolveria este problema de outra forma baha

Comment: Eu não discordo que haja soluções que usem variável variável e consigam ser mais elegantes. O que me pega é que o código fica menos legível e potencialmente confuso. Então digo por aí pra evitar como regra geral. Mas toda regra tem exceções :)