# Variáveis de variáveis PHP

Tags: php

Então estava a estudar um código aqui, e deparei-me com uma **variável de variável**.

Já ouvi falar muito deste conceito mas ate hoje ainda não entendi para que elas servem, quando devemos usar etc..

Então minhas questões são:

- O que são variáveis de variáveis e para que servem?
- Devemos usar Variáveis de variáveis?, **se sim em que situações?**
- Variáveis de variáveis, têm algum efeito no performance da aplicação php ?

Se possível com exemplos.

Comment: Relacionada: [Variável variável em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171153/vari%C3%A1vel-vari%C3%A1vel-em-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Relacionada²: [Que utilidade tem esta forma de acessar valores de variaveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217704/28595)

Comment: já tinha olhado antes de publicar mas acho que não abrange todas as minhas questões

Comment: Creio que todas as duvidas estão sanadas nos link que o @Articuno postou. De qualquer forma, preferi votar para fechar como ampla e não como duplicata por entender que a pergunta foge um pouco da proposta do site (muitas dúvidas em uma postagem só). Fica a sugestão de leitura do [tour]. [ask], e depois [edit] a pergunta para deixá-la apenas com a dúvida específica, caso realmente haja algo não satisfeito nas outras postagens. Lembre-se que quando tiver dúvidas, pode ir perguntando sobre uma parte por vez, e postar novas questões quando a anterior for sanada.

Comment: **Possível** duplicata de [O que é uma variável escalar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230291/o-que-%c3%a9-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-escalar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom acredito que vc queira dizer variável variável e não variável de variável

- O que são variáveis de variáveis e para que servem?

Um nome de variável que pode ser configurado e usado dinamicamente. Uma variável variável assume o valor de uma variável e trata-a como o nome de uma variável.

- Devemos usar Variáveis de variáveis?, se sim em que situações?

São mais úteis ao acessar valores dentro de uma propriedade que contém uma matriz, quando o nome da propriedade é feito de várias partes, ou quando o nome da propriedade contém caracteres que não são válidos (por exemplo, de json_decode () ou SimpleXML ).

Acho que o melhor exemplo para entender a sua utilização é este:

```
<?php 
$varname = "foo"; 
$foo = "bar"; 

print $$varname;  // Prints "bar" 
print "$$varname";  // Prints "$foo" 
print "${$varname}"; // Prints "bar" 
?>
```

E para mim ao menos, a maior utilidade que possui é quando vc possui nomes de variáveis compostos, porém que possuem parte do nome igual remetendo a algo, então vc coloca apenas uma lista da diferenciação destas variáveis em um vetor e com um foreach lista todos, como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
// Given these variables ...
$nameTypes    = array("first", "last", "company");
$name_first   = "John";
$name_last    = "Doe";
$name_company = "PHP.net";

// Then this loop is ...
foreach($nameTypes as $type)
  print ${"name_$type"} . "\n";

// ... equivalent to this print statement.
print "$name_first\n$name_last\n$name_company\n";
?>
```

- Variáveis de variáveis, têm algum efeito no performance da aplicação php ?

Olhe se tem melhora na performance não sei, mas acredito que não, o que sei é que possui otimização de código como demonstrado no exemplo anterior.

Todos os exemplos e exceções vc pode encontrar na documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php